# Is it possible on button click event change the sequence of list?

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I am new in `Sitecore analytics`, anyone can guide me on how to achieve reorder of the list after button click using `Sitecore analytics`? There are below use case.

**Case 1:** I have a car list e.g. Ciaz, Baleno, etc.

> Each car having  "Explore" button, if we click on Ciaz car's Explore button, then our list should start from Ciaz=> Baleno=>X-Cross, etc.
>   if we click on Baleno Explore button then the list should start from Baleno=>Ciaz=>X-cross etc.

**Case 2:** Explore Button become exist on any page, If we click on Explore Button
from any page after this, when we visit on listing page, the list should be displayed respective click.
e.g. If we click on home page banner of  Baleno on Explore button, car listing page will show like

> Baleno=>Ciaz=>X-Cross, etc.

Please, anyone, help me how to achieve this from `Sitecore analytics`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create goals for each car, you can see this link:

https://horizontalintegration.blog/2015/11/30/configuring-goals-in-sitecore/

that how to create goals, after that you can apply personalization on the basis of goals on listing component.

Please find personalization link:

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/personalizing-components.html

You can create custom rule as well